# Match contents before and after an optional word in string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, pcre

I have the following lines:

```
After=netfilter-persistent.service network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service netfilter-persistent.service
After=anothertest netfilter-persistent.service network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service
```

And I'm

1. looking for a regex which captures the contents after `After=` and before and after `netfilter-persistent.service`, and
2. everything after `After=` if `netfilter-persistent.service` is not present.

This regex does 1 but not 2:

```
^After=(.*?)?(?:netfilter-persistent\.service)(.*?)?$
```

This regex does 2 but not 1:

```
^After=(.*?)?(?:netfilter-persistent\.service)?(.*?)?$
```

This one comes close but then `netfilter-persistent.service` is still in Group 1:

```
^After=(.*?(?:netfilter-persistent\.service))?(.*?)?$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make the first group non-capturing in your last pattern and wrap the `.*?` with a capturing group use

```
^After=(?:(.*?)netfilter-persistent\.service)?(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dCzRz1/2)

**Details**

- `^After=` - `After` substring at the start of the string
- `(?:(.*?)netfilter-persistent\.service)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `netfilter-persistent\.service` - a `netfilter-persistent.service` substring
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible up to...
- `$` - the end of the string.

Comment: Awesome that works. Youve saved me a couple of hours.
Can you explain why
```^After=(.*?)?(?:netfilter-persistent\.service)?(.*?)?$``` 
does not work? I would expect it did

Comment: @ChessSpider You may check how the pattern matches string [here](https://regex101.com/r/YUgAJI/2/debugger). After matching `After=` with `^After=`, the regex engines tries `(.*?)?`, finds an empty string, and goes on to try `(?:netfilter-persistent\.service)?`. It cannot match `netfilter-persistent.service` as it is not right after `After=`, so an empty match is grabbed. Then,  the last `(?:.*?)` grabs all up to the end and puts the submatch into Group 2.